# Why is T not recognized as the template parameter in this function?

Tags: c++, templates

I have code like the following:

```cpp
class Foo
{
public:
    template<typename R, typename T, typename S>
    static R add(T x, S y) { return x + y; }
};

template<typename Foo, typename T>
inline T add(T x, double y)
{
    return Foo::add<T, T, double>(x, y);
}
```

My expectation was to obtain a free function callable like `SomeType add<Foo>(SomeType, double)`.

(The idea is that `Foo` and other classes that define a similar templated `add` need only specify the calculation once, and the return type disambiguation is done by a number of free functions.)

Instead, the code fails to compile (https://ideone.com/ZI0v0M):

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘T add(T, double)’:
prog.cpp:11:19: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
  return Foo::add<T, T, double>(x, y);
                   ^
prog.cpp:11:22: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
  return Foo::add<T, T, double>(x, y);
                      ^
prog.cpp:11:24: error: expected primary-expression before ‘double’
  return Foo::add<T, T, double>(x, y);
                        ^~~~~~
prog.cpp:11:23: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘double’
  return Foo::add<T, T, double>(x, y);
                       ^~~~~~~
                       ;
prog.cpp:11:30: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘>’ token
  return Foo::add<T, T, double>(x, y);
                              ^
```

Why is `T` not being interpreted as the template parameter here?

Comment: **tl;dr** of the dupes: `Foo::template add<T, T, double>(x, y)`

Comment: typename Foo is not required here because it's the actual class foo, otherwise you'll need to call it with add<Foo>(3, 4.5); (and `Foo:: template add(...`, I think)

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica That's it, thanks.
@Borgleader I realize that my naming is confusing here. The intention is for this to work across a range of types, not just `Foo`.